# Rendered attribute like JSF in Play Framework 2.0

Tags: playframework-2.0

Is in play framework exist something similiar like rendered attrubite in JSF ?

I have a form:

```
    @checkbox(parametersForm("checkDuplicates"), '_label -> "Check duplicates")
    @checkbox(parametersForm("checkDuplicatesCaseSensitive"), '_label -> "Case-sensitive check duplicates")
```

And I have bean to post this parameters with two boolean variables 'checkDuplicates' and 'checkDuplicatesCaseSensitive':

```
@(parametersForm: Form[ImportController.ImportParameters])
```

I want to achieve results when checkbox case-sensitive will be visible for user only when check duplicates will be checked.

I know I can do that using simple java script but I've been interesting is exist for this embedded mechanism (showing / hiding fields depends on other fields). I suspect it can be possible with set hidden value in input like

```
 'hidden -> @parametersForm.get.checkDuplicates==true
```

but I new in scala hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap your field with `@if - else` condition

```
@if(parametersForm.get("checkDuplicates").value==true) {
    @checkbox(parametersForm("someAlt"), '_label -> "Some alt")
}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile, it should be: parametersForm("checkDuplicates").value=="true" and I'm looking for client side mechanism.

Comment: Play2 doesn't provide client side mechanisms

Comment: My fault, written from top of my head, sry. Anyway as @JulienLafont wrote, there's no client side mechanics, so you just able to use any JS framework you wish